# How to turn vanilla js fetch code into react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I wrote this code in Vanilla JS

```
function MovieGrid() {
fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(function(res){
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return( `<ul>
    <li><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${data.results.poster_path}" alt="" /></li>
    <li>${data.results.title}</li>
    </ul>`)
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });}
```

This code works in vanilla but the app I'm working on is developed in react. So how do I turn this code above to working react component?

Comment: What have you tried so far to do that? :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Fetch Data in React Using the Fetch API

Always make network request after the component mounted

Use fetch API inside `useEffect()` if you are using functional component

example:

```
import {
  useEffect
} from 'react';


const Component = () => {

  useEffect(() => {

    // use fetch inside here

  }, [])

  return (
    // .... JSX Element
  )
}

export default Component;
```

Use fetch API inside `componentDidMount()` if you are using class component;

More helpful article in this link **[fetch data in react](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/)**

Comment: doesn't work, it gives me this error
Uncaught Error: MovieGrid(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
    React 13
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:468
    React 6
react-dom.development.js:14169
and no,the return statement is not empty

Comment: You should Invistigate more thouroughly, But thats the way on how to use fetch in react